# How to implement strlen as fast as possible

Tags: c++, algorithm

Assume that you're working a x86 32-bits system. Your task is to implement the strlen as fast as possible.

There're two problems you've to take care:
1. address alignment.
2. read memory with machine word length(4 bytes).

It's not hard to find the first alignment address in the given string.

Then we can read memory once with the 4 bytes, and count up it the total length. But we should  stop once there's a zero byte in the 4 bytes, and count the left bytes before zero byte. In order to check the zero byte in a fast way, there's a code snippet from glibc:

```
unsigned long int longword, himagic, lomagic;
himagic = 0x80808080L;  
lomagic = 0x01010101L;

// There's zero byte in 4 bytes.
if (((longword - lomagic) & ~longword & himagic) != 0) {
    // do left thing...
}
```

I used it in Visual C++, to compare with CRT's implementation. The CRT's is much more faster than the above one.

I'm not familiar with CRT's implementation, did they use a faster way to check the zero byte?

Comment: Do you have any numbers on the differences? Did you enable full optimization when compiling the above code?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the strlen that comes with your respective compiler/library? Chances are the library writers have spent some time getting all possible optimizations already. Also as alluded in an answer since this is tagged C++ can you use std::string which should store the length?

Comment: @Mark, it was probably a homework assignment, hence the *“your task is to implement strlen”*. While performance does not appear to have been part of the question, the OP was trying to figure out why the implementation they came up with so slow.

Comment: Do you compiled your code with optimizations enabled and in release mode? Check also this [source code](http://www.lrdev.com/lr/c/strlen.c).

Comment: Those **'L' suffixes** are making your compiler **upgrade all operations to 64-bits!**
Remove them and see my complete answer below [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24805807/501336]

Comment: For more details on @gatopeich's assertion, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os. Funny that you would find that code in glibc, since it is expected to work on architectures with 64-bit `long` types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First CRT's one is written **directly** in assembler. you can see it's source code here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\intel\strlen.asm` (this is for VS 2008)

Answer (score 8):

You could save the length of the string along with the string when creating it, as is done in Pascal.

Comment: +1 I'm not exactly sure that this addresses the question, but, seriously, null-terminated strings are among the biggest weaknesses of the C language and lead to ridiculous big-O performance times with naïve code. Best to avoid them entirely.

Comment: Yep. You should only ever compute strlen once, and then cache that result. An advantage of using string classes in C++. Of course, as stated, this doesn't help with your problem.

Comment: and, like so many other things, this weakness of C++ has become ingrained into other languages and operating systems, ad infinitum

Comment: @BlueRaja: this weakness of `C`, `C++` has `std::string` which often has a constant-time `size` member-function... although it's not required by the standard.

Comment: @Matthieu: `"abcd"` has type `char[]`, not `std::string`, which causes the weakness to still be pervasive

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: C++14 offers true string literals, so you don't have to use C string literals nearly as often (and having checked compiler output, it does the right thing, passing the length of the literal computed at compile time to the constructor so it's not recomputing the length, and the literal can have embedded `NUL`s). Just change `"abcd"` to `"abcd"s`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Microsoft's library really has two different versions of strlen. One is a portable version in C that's about the most trivial version of strlen possible, pretty close (and probably equivalent) to:

```
size_t strlen(char const *str) { 
    for (char const *pos=str; *pos; ++pos)
        ;
    return pos-str;
}
```

The other is in assembly language (used only for Intel x86), and quite similar to what you have above, at least as far as load 4 bytes, check of one of them is zero, and react appropriately. The only obvious difference is that instead of subtracting, they basically add pre-negate the bytes and add. I.e. instead of `word-0x0101010101`, they use `word + 0x7efefeff`.

Comment: Can I find the source code of Microsoft's strlen implementation in assembly language without MS-VS install on my machine? I'm not on MS-windows,but I'm very curious to try to understand your last comment and checks how fast it is.

Comment: @Jack: I suppose you could look on their web site, but I'm not sure if it's there. My guess is that the easiest/most dependable way to find it is to install VS (but I believe VS Express should work, if you don't want to buy it).

Answer (score 2):

there are also compiler intrinsic versions which use the REPNE SCAS instruction pair, though these are generally on older compilers, they can still be pretty fast. there are also SSE2 versions of strlen, such as [Dr Agner Fog's performance library's implementation](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib), or something such as [this](http://www.strchr.com/sse2_optimised_strlen)

Answer (score 1):

Remove those 'L' suffixes and see... *You are promoting all calculations to "long"!* On my 32-bits tests, that alone doubles the cost.

I also do two micro-optimizations:

- Since most strings we use scan consist of ASCII chars in the range 0~127, the **high bit is (almost) never set**, so only check for it in a second test.
- **Increment an index rather than a pointer**, which is cheaper on some architectures (notably x86) and give you the length for 'free'...

---

```
uint32_t gatopeich_strlen32(const char* str)
{
    uint32_t *u32 = (uint32_t*)str, u, abcd, i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        u = u32[i++];
        abcd = (u-0x01010101) & 0x80808080;
        if (abcd && // If abcd is not 0, we have NUL or a non-ASCII char > 127...
             (abcd &= ~u)) // ... Discard non-ASCII chars
        {
        #if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
            return 4*i - (abcd&0xffff0000 ? (abcd&0xff000000?4:3) : abcd&0xff00?2:1);
        #else
            return 4*i - (abcd&0xffff ? (abcd&0xff?4:3) : abcd&0xff0000?2:1);
        #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The extra branch added by the conditional `&&` probably loses more than you save by skipping one operation. Hard to know for sure without benchmarking though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the maximum possible length, and you've initated the memory to \0 before use, you could do a binary split and go left/right depending on the value(\0, split on left, else split on right). That way you'd dramatically decrease the amount of checks you'll need to find the length. Not optimal(requires some setup), but should be really fast.

// Eric

Comment: this implies that you append NUL characters until the end of the buffer every time you modify the content of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, crafting a tight loop like this in assembler would be fastest, however if you want/need to keep it more human-readable and/or portable in C(++), you can still increase the speed of the standard function by using the [`register` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482s4fy9.aspx).

The `register` keyword prompts the compiler to store the counter in a register on the CPU instead of in memory which will significantly speed up the loop.

Note however, that the `register` keyword is only a suggestion and the compiler is free to ignore it if it thinks it can do better, especially if certain optimization options are used. That said, while it is almost certainly going to be ignored for a local, class variable in a triple for-loop, it is likely to be honored for the code below, thus improving performance quite a bit (nearly on par with the assembler version):

```
size_t strlen ( const char* s ) {
  for (register const char* i=s; *i; ++i);
  return (i-s);
}
```

Comment: No sane compiler would consider storing such a loop iterator *not* in a register...

Comment: Which is why—as I clearly said—the `register` keyword is just a *hint*, not an iron-clad command.